# need reference for fact about products of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Need a reference (textbook or paper) for the following (probably well known) fact: 
Suppose $(X,M)$ is a measurable space and $\lambda$, $\nu$ are two different probability measures on $(X,M)$. Write $\lambda^\infty$, $\nu^\infty$ for the corresponding infinite product measures on the $(X^\infty ,M^\infty )$. Then 
$\lambda^\infty$ and $\nu^\infty$ are mutually singular.

Comment: Doesn't address your question in general, but you might also be interested in the following theorem due to Kakutani: for each $n$ suppose that $\mu_n, \nu_n$ are two probability measures on a measurable space $(X_n, M_n)$, with $\nu_n \ll \mu_n$.  Let $\mu = \bigotimes \mu_n$, $\nu = \bigotimes \nu_n$ be the corresponding product measures on the space $X = \prod X_n$ with its product $\sigma$-algebra.  Then either $\nu \ll \mu$ or $\nu \perp \mu$, according to whether the infinite product $\prod_n \int_{X_n} \sqrt{\frac{d \nu_n}{d \mu_n}}\,d\mu_n$ is nonzero or zero.

Comment: You can find a proof via martingales in Bogachev's *Measure Theory* as Theorem 10.3.6.

Comment: There is also a good discussion of Kakutani's result in Chapter 14 of *Probability with Martingales* by David Williams.

Comment: @NateEldredge You or Byron or someone should pack that into an answer, imo.

Answer (score 8):

Use the strong law of large numbers.
Choose $B\in M$ so that $\lambda(B)\neq \mu(B)$, and consider the disjoint sets
$$\left\{x\in X^\infty: {1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n 1_{[x_j\in B]}\to \lambda(B)\right\}\mbox{ and }\left\{x\in X^\infty: {1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n 1_{[x_j\in B]}\to \mu(B)\right\}.$$

Comment: Cool. Would have been quicker for me to see the point if you'd considered this set as well as the set where the limit is $\mu(B)$; they're disjoint, each has full measure wrt one of the measures.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That was a good suggestion, thanks!